# How to make the Android navigation bar do not respond automatically?

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

I've written this application that has a button (the layout is all full so I cannot simply move it) that its close to the back, home and the two rectangle button of my android tablet. this means that once in a while I accidentally pressed the home or back button and I get taken away from my app. It is really annoying. From what I've read it is not possible to hide o disable this bar. However, is there any way that I can make it so I have to touch the navigation bar twice before it responds? Like once for the button to appear and another time to actually issue the command?

I have in my

```
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState):
```

this code:

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

However two problems: 1) If I touche the button I immediately get taken out of my app and 2) Untill I kill my app and restart it the bar does not dim again (This can be solved by putting the code for the low profile somewhere else, but I don't know where).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did exactly what I wanted:

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    //Making the navigation bar requiere two commands to be used.
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //Making the navigation bar requiere two commands to be used.
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

The navigation buttons are still visible however the first time you press it nothing will happen. If you presse it again it will do what is supposed to, but If you go back to the activity this you will need to presse it twice again. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 4.4 (API 19) you actually can hide the bottom navigation bar with the new "immersive mode". The navigation and system bars will be revealed again when the user inward-swipes vertically along the top. See https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html on how to achieve this. Note that immersive mode is not ideal, ux-wise, for just any app. Games and video apps are probably best suited for immersive mode. As for overriding the behaviour of the navigation buttons, you can do this, to a certain extent, if your app is the home app (i.e., the launcher). That, however, is certainly not acceptable unless your app actually is a launcher in nature. Nevertheless, if that's the way you want to go, your activity should have the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is just to get you started though, there's a lot of work involved with a launcher...

Comment: It is not acceptable, as you say because my app is not a launcher. The android version you ask for is too new (my tablet is a Xoom). However I did manage to get it to do what I wanted by reworking a bit of my code. And yes, as a matter of fact, my app is a game.